# Change Circle shape of Thumb in Slider Jetpack compose

Tags: android, user-interface, slider, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

The Slider in Jetpack Compose allows changing the color of the thumb but not the shape.
I'm looking solution to change the shape of the thumb from circle to rectangle as represented in the attached image

[image]

I tried to add [Slider.kt](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/compose/material/material/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/Slider.kt) file to the project as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69053570/9994543) but, strangely, when I copy this code to the project I got a lot of errors, see attached screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 5):

With **M3** `androidx.compose.material3.Slider` you can use the **`thumb`** attribute to use a custom thumb.

You can use a simple `Spacer` or a `Box` to obtain a Rectangle:

```
var sliderPosition by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
val interactionSource = MutableInteractionSource()

Column {
    Text(text = sliderPosition.toString())

    Slider(
        modifier = Modifier.semantics { contentDescription = "Localized Description" },
        value = sliderPosition,
        onValueChange = { sliderPosition = it },
        valueRange = 0f..5f,
        steps = 4,
        interactionSource = interactionSource,
        onValueChangeFinished = {
            // launch some business logic update with the state you hold
        },
        thumb = {
            val shape = RectangleShape 
            Spacer(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(20.dp)
                    .indication(
                        interactionSource = interactionSource,
                        indication = rememberRipple(
                            bounded = false,
                            radius = 20.dp
                        )
                    )
                    .hoverable(interactionSource = interactionSource)
                    .shadow(if (enabled) 6.dp else 0.dp, shape, clip = false)
                    .background(Red, shape)
            )
        },
    )
}
```

[image]

**Note:** it requires for `material3` at least the version `1.0.0-beta03`

Comment: What is `interactionSource` and from where can I get its object?

Comment: @BugsHappen just `val interactionSource = MutableInteractionSource()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a source code for [`Slider` composable](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/material/material/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/Slider.kt).

You can copy it to your project, rename, and change the Thumb shape in the `SliderThumb` composable:

```
...
.shadow(if (enabled) elevation else 0.dp, CircleShape, clip = false)
.background(colors.thumbColor(enabled).value, CircleShape)
...
```

Comment: I edited the question, this solution doesn't helped me and I think that should be an easy way to resolve this

Comment: Remove "package androidx.compose.material" from your Slider.kt, if its slill there, agree to all IDE's import suggestions, and everything should work. There is no easier way, thumb shape is hardcoded inside private function.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [ShapeSlider](https://github.com/louiewh/ShapeSlider) : The "Compose slider" supports Track and Thumb designed by self using Shape or Modifier

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35320866)